# Can Quick Search be set up so External ID does not have to be exact match to work?

Tags: quicksearch, external-id

Tested on dmaster.

Give Contact external ID eg fz123456

then set QuickSearch for External ID and enter

- fz123 - no result
- fz1234 - no result
- fz12345 - no result
- fz123456 - yay

Ah, see this applies to Internal ID too, namely

- 2 - Muller
- 20 - ah.olsen@
- 202 - demo@
- 2% - Muller

Can you reset QuickSearch so these match with wildcards?

Answer (score 1):

I originally wrote it that way to avoid confusion. If you want to pull up contact id `20` you'll be overwhelmed with irrelevant results (201, 202, 203, 120, 220, 320, and so on). You'll get so many results that the one you actually wanted might not even be in the list!

That said, if someone had time and/or money for the project, I'm sure there could be something smart added to the query that made the exact match show up first in the list followed by partial matches.